# Is it possible to count visible children if parent(s) are hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I don't know if is possible to do this...so i want an explanation.

I have this situation:

```
   <div id="grandfather" style="display:none">
    <div id="ipocentro-quakes">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div style="display:none"></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
   </div>

    var selezioni_attive= ($('#ipocentro-quakes > div:visible').length)-1;
```

I would an output like **2** because counting i don't consider first children and all hidden childrens (in my case only one, the third).

But my output is **-1**.

Is possible to do this also if there's `#grandfather` with `display:none` ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `:not(:firstchild)` to skip first element, and `not([style*="display: none"])` to skip the elements with `display:none`:

```
var selezioni_attive = 
    ($('#ipocentro-quakes > div:not(:firstchild):not([style*="display: none"])').length)-1;
```

Comment: and if "display:none" to #grandfather is not add like css inline ?

Comment: Keep in mind that the visibility can be set in the CSS, so style attribute would not apply.  In fact, inline styling should be discouraged in the HTML

Comment: Using this method you have to be very careful when writing your inline css. Although 'display: none', 'display:none' , 'display : none','display :none' (pay attention to the space) all means the same style. Only 'display: none' would fall into the answer's selection rule

Comment: ^ yep.  whitespace and case sensitivity could play a factor

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the children list, and iterate it, checking one by one each child element visibility:

In Vanila JS :

```js
let count = 0;
let parent = document.getElementById('ipocentro-quakes');
Array.from(parent.children).forEach( e=>{
  // get child index
  let index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent.children, e);
  // ignore first child
  if(index===0)  return;
  // get style of child
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(e);
  // if it's visible, increase counter
  if (style.display !== 'none') count++;
})
console.log('total visible:',count)
```

```html
<div id="grandfather" style="display:none">
  <div id="ipocentro-quakes">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div style="display:none"></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

## Compact version

Provided by @Jaromanda-X in the comments

```
let count = Array.from(parent.children).slice(1).filter(e => window.getComputedStyle(e).display !== 'none').length;
```

Comment: or, `let count = Array.from(parent.children).slice(1).filter(e => window.getComputedStyle(e).display !== 'none').length;`

Comment: super elegant! do you let me include it in my answer ?

Comment: it's all yours!

Comment: love it, it's brilliant ;)

Comment: Probably will be the fastest solution, however the labeling is off.  It's not the total visible.  It's the total found, none of these are actually visible on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery document reads:

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Since divs' parent is `display:none`, they will take no space as well, thus considered invisible

How about do it by using class name

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selezioni_attive = $("#ipocentro-quakes > div:not(.invisible)").length;

  console.log(selezioni_attive);
});
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grandfather" style="display:none">
  <div id="ipocentro-quakes">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What i'm suggesting is to use class name to control visibility instead of inline css, and using class name to count element as well. The answer is not using ":visible" (jQuery extension), but instead "div:not(.invisible)" (css standard)

Comment: Yep, correct ;), now the only condition where it wouldn't be counted is if the class was not used `div:last-child { display:none; }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible:

```js
let found = $('#grandfather')
              .find(':not(:first-child)')
              .filter((i, el) => el.style.display != 'none')
              .length;

console.log(found)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grandfather" style="display:none">
  <div id="ipocentro-quakes">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div style="display:none"></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- select the ancestor
- find everything that's not a first child
- of those only filter out the ones that are visible